# django insert a raw to msql

Tags: mysql, django

I am a fresh hand at django. I want to insert a new row into MySQL database, but when I trying to do as following, it goes error.

```
from django.db import models
...
class Msg(models.Model):
    MsgId = BigIntegerField(length = 20)
    ToUserName = CharField(max_length = 45)
    FromUserName = CharField(max_length = 45)
    Content = TextField(max_length = 1024, blank = True)
...
db_entry = Msg(MsgId=received_MsgId, ToUserName=received_ToUserName,
               FromUserName=received_FromUserName, MsgType=received_MsgType,
               Content=received_Content)
db_entry.save()
```

This following is the table `all_massages` existing in my database, and how can I add a new row to it, and what extra things I need to do.

```
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| MsgId        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ToUserName   | varchar(45)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| FromUserName | varchar(45)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Content      | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Do you mean `row` (record) instead of `raw`? What error are you getting?

Comment: Do this code really lives in a single file, or have you pasted code from multiple files? You want us to "assume there is a table all_massages", but usually it is Django that creates tables from models (and the name of the table would be different then). Do you want to use Django with a legacy db with existing models?

Comment: 'it goes error', what error?

Answer (score 1):

If you have altered mode and executed syncdb ...it wont work....so delete the existing table and execute syncdb!!

Answer (score 0):

Django documentation clearly specifies how to perform raw sql queries.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries

For directly executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE queries.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly